# How to enable the <br /> tag in Wordpress posts and pages

Tags: visual-editor, post-editor, wp-autop, line-breaks

i can't understand why so simple feature are disabled by Wordpress Team.
I want have line breaking with "br" tag.

On one wordpress forum was idea to modificate editor.js (in wp-admin/js) and formating.php (in wp-includes) files. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/ltbrgt-stripping-problem-ultimate-solving

I was tryed to do this, but 0 good results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, modifying core files is extremely frowned upon you will have to make these changes with every upgrade and they can lead to security and other problems.

I'm pretty sure there is a plugin that will allow this. I did a simple search and here are a few to try:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/preserved-html-editor-markup/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/

Comment: Ok, all is working now.
In Ultimate-tinymce we must enable option: "Enable Line Break Shortcode".
Then with [break] shortcode we can simply put <br> tag.
Thanks @BandonRandon